# var results in the function as string and not the result

Tags: javascript

I have a function that looks like this but for some reason it keeps returning the actual function in text then the result....how do I get it to return the result from the if statement and not the whole function as text?

```
    var xLbl = function () {

        if (yAxistm.tm === 'yr') {

            return "Year";

        } else if (yAxistm.tm === 'qtr') {

            return "Quarter";

        } else if (yAxistm.tm === 'mth') {

            return "Month";

        };

    };

    console.log("xLable: ", xLbl);
```

result:

```
xLable:  function () {

            if (yAxistm.tm === 'yr') {

                return "Year";

            } else if (yAxistm.tm === 'qtr') {

                return "Quarter";

            } else…
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the open and close parenthesis "()" after you type name of the function.
`console.log("xLable: ", xLbl());`

[This page explains everything](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the value of `xLbl` which is a function. What you are trying to do is call the function. It should look like this `console.log("xLabel: ", xLbl());`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print out the function definition..

You need to **invoke** the function

```
console.log("xLabel: ", xLbl());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function:

```
console.log("xLable: ", xLbl());
```